# Java Robot.mousemove() doesn't move the cursor on linux. only the pointer

Tags: java, linux, debian

The problem is that after this code the mouse cursor stays at the same place but it acts as if it is on 0,0 but if i move my mouse it just moving the cursor as if it was never moved.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot r=new Robot();
            r.mouseMove(0,0);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the Mouse to move with the cursor like when i run this code on Windows.
P.S.: I don't Run this code on VM

Comment: It's obviously just me but, what does this even mean? `"but if i move my mouse it just moving the cursor as if it was never moved."`

Comment: It means that the cursor doesn't change its Position and when i move my mouse it moves the cursor from the position it was located. So the mouseMove doesn't affect the cursor at all

Comment: So you're saying that you want to see the animation of the mouse pointer moving from its original position to your programmed position? I haven't touched the Robot class in a while, but IIRC, the call to mouseMove occurs instantly, so you can't *see* any evidence of the move, but it does, indeed happen because you can call mouseDown or mouseClick at the new location and activate some UI element there. Sounds like you just expect an animation. Is that so?

Comment: No the problem is that the cursor stays at his plays and doesn't move at all, but when i click to example the Left Button It behaves as if the cursor moved. But when i move the mouse it moves the cursor with my mouse it just moves normally from the position it was before mouseMove as if Nothing happend

Comment: OK, well, I have no idea what's happening for you, because your code works as posted. My mouse pointer does indeed move. How are you running your code? Are you using an IDE or console?

Comment: Yes i just asked my friend to run it on his Ubuntu and its working perfectly im considering suicide at this point. Its just not funny anymore WTF isn't it working for me i have no idea

Comment: Why don't you start by answering my question? Are you running your code in an IDE or via console?

Comment: To verify that the mouse pointer (aka: Mouse Cursor) has indeed moved place the following code lines *under* the `r.mouseMove(0,0);`.  Copy/Paste these two lines: `Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); System.out.println("x = " + p.x + ", y = " + p.y);`.